# Why does Chrome not show up the default value to 'input type="date"' on mobile?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, date, mobile

I'm just making a site for study proposes...
When I'm on desktop, the `input type="date"` shows up a default value with the letters dd/mm/aaaa...
[on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN0zl.jpg)

But when I'm on my mobile (Android), the `input type="date"` shows an empty field...
[on mobile Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/141YX.jpg)

The code is (I'm using Bootstrap 3):

```
...
<div>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="data" name="data" style="width:65%;" required>
</div>
...
```

I tried `placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"` too... But without success...

Why is this happening?
Could someone help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please view the edited answer, it has much more insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android WebKit 4 is such a mess that it needs its own, private compatibility table for some types.

Although the implementations of `<input type="date" >` are different across the various mobile OS platforms, support is quite widespread, with the exception of the stock Android browser.

For this browser and for low-end devices a simple text field will be displayed. This is not very user-friendly for date input.

As you are using bootstrap I reccomend going through : [this](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

**EDIT** :

I found an interesting way of solving this issue :
A tool called Modernizr tells you what HTML, CSS and JavaScript features the user’s browser has to offer. Using that you can try the following which shows how you can use the native datepicker when available, and fallback to jQuery UI’s picker in unsupported browsers(in this case : Chrome -> Android Webkit).

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
    $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
        // Consistent format with the HTML5 picker
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
}
```

Your complete code will look like this :

HTML:

```
<input type="date">

<br><br>

<input type="text" id="myDate" />
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function() {
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes['date']) {
        $('input[type=date]').datepicker();
    }
});
```