# input type="date" doesn't work with android browser

Tags: android, date, input

Input type="date" doesn't work with  with android browser but work on chrome inspector  with mobile device simulator for all android mobile .
[image: Input type="date" on simulator android samsung A51 device with inspector]

It is impossible to modify the year directly, I must click previous month until the year to target .[image: Input Date Android].
The previous and after bouton modify the month. When I click on year there is nothing !

Input type="month" work perfectly (mobile and desktop) allowing to choose separately month and year
[image: Input type month android]

What can I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Are your tried all browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc... or its not working in only chrome?

Comment: all browsers from android (Huawei p30 (EMUI 12) = android 11 ? I think, I can't retrieve the exact version).
all last version : chrome, edge, firefox , brave, opera.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47438091/12709358

Comment: I'm sorry, the selection of date work by clicking on the year on the top . But it's not intuitive. If I have not undestood immediately lot of user won't understand either. 
the solution provided doesn't change anything. 
perhaps this presentation appears only huawei and android 11 ?